# custom directive ends with `syntax error, unexpected '<'`

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to add a custom directive to blade. I use the example form the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade#extending-blade) and added the following code:

AppServiceProvider.php

```
Blade::directive('datetime', function ($expression) {
    return "<?php echo ($expression)->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>";
});
```

home.blade.php

```
{{ @datetime(new \DateTime()) }}
```

after running `view:clear` and browse to the page, I've got this error at the directive line:

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
> syntax error, unexpected '<' (View: /var/www/html/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's too easy: To use a directive don't add curly brackets:

home.blade.php

```
@datetime(new \DateTime())
```